# Looping over a MultiIndex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a MultiIndexed DataFrame df1, and would like to loop over it in such a way as to in each instance of the loop have a DataFrame with a regular non-hierarchical index which is the subset of df1 corresponding to the outer index entries. I.e., if i have:

[image: FirstTable]

I want to get

[image: SecondTable]

and subsequently C1, C2, etc. I also don't know what the names of these will actually be (C1, etc., just being placeholders here), so would just like to loop over the number of C<sub>i</sub> values I have.

I have been stumbling around with `iterrows` and various loops and not getting any tangible results and don't really know how to proceed. I feel like a simple solution should exist but couldn't find anything that looked helpful in the documentation, probably due to my own lack of understanding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a modified example from [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#multiindexing-using-slicers)

```
In [30]: def mklbl(prefix,n):
        return ["%s%s" % (prefix,i)  for i in range(n)]
   ....: 

In [31]: columns = MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a','foo'),('a','bar'),
                                  ('b','foo'),('b','bah')],
                                   names=['lvl0', 'lvl1'])

In [33]: index = MultiIndex.from_product([mklbl('A',4),mklbl('B',2)])

In [34]: df = DataFrame(np.arange(len(index)*len(columns)).reshape((len(index),len(columns))),
               index=index,
               columns=columns).sortlevel().sortlevel(axis=1)

In [35]: df
Out[35]: 
lvl0     a         b     
lvl1   bar  foo  bah  foo
A0 B0    1    0    3    2
   B1    5    4    7    6
A1 B0    9    8   11   10
   B1   13   12   15   14
A2 B0   17   16   19   18
   B1   21   20   23   22
A3 B0   25   24   27   26
   B1   29   28   31   30

In [36]: df.loc['A0']
Out[36]: 
lvl0    a         b     
lvl1  bar  foo  bah  foo
B0      1    0    3    2
B1      5    4    7    6

In [37]: df.loc['A1']
Out[37]: 
lvl0    a         b     
lvl1  bar  foo  bah  foo
B0      9    8   11   10
B1     13   12   15   14
```

No looping is necessary.

You can also select these in order to return a frame (with the original MI)
e.g. `df.loc[['A1']]`

If you want to get the values in the index:

```
In [38]: df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()
Out[38]: array(['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work if I know what the label is,  but what do I do if I don't? ie. I don't know the names of the index (in my problem, they (A in your example) are minutes in which at least one event occurred, and the sub index (B in your example) contains the seconds at which specific events occurred). i don't know when the events occurred. Also, your example doesn't iterate through all elements of the index and I want to loop through every minute.

Comment: updated to show how to get the level values. Looping is straightforward if you really want to loop.

Comment: @jeff can you take a look at this [use case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352742/pandas-design-considerations-for-multiindexed-dataframes)?

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
for i in set(df.index):
    print df.loc[i].reset_index()
```

1. `set(df.index)` returns a set of unique tuples of your multi-index (hierarchical index).
2. `df.loc[i].reset_index()`... `df.loc[i]` of course returns a subset of your original dataframe, and the `.reset_index()` part will convert the index to columns

Comment: Very useful for a related question:  how convert multindex to an iterable of tuples.  Thanks!