# Pandas Design Considerations for MultiIndexed Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

The purpose of this question is to further explore [MultiIndex dataframes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) and to ask questions of the best approach for various tasks.

**Create the DataFrame**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'index_date' : ['12/07/2016','12/07/2016','12/07/2016','12/07/2016','12/07/2016'], 
               'portfolio' : ['A','B','C','D','E'], 
               'reporting_ccy' : ['GBP','GBP','GBP','GBP','GBP'],
               'portfolio_ccy' : ['JPY','USD','USD','EUR','EUR'],
               'amount' : [100,200,300,400,500],
               'injection' : [1,2,3,4,5],
               'to_usd' : [1.3167,1.3167,1.3167,1.3167,1.3167],
               'to_ccy' : [0.009564,1,1,1.1093,1.1093],
               'm5' : [2,4,6,8,10],
               'm6' : [1,3,5,7,9]});
```

**Pivot the DataFrame**

```
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index='index_date',columns=['portfolio','portfolio_ccy','reporting_ccy']).swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1).sortlevel(axis=1)
```

**Rename the columns**

```
df_pivot.columns.names = ['portfolio','measures', 'portfolio_ccy', 'reporting_ccy']
```

This yields a pivoted representation of the data such that:

1. a portfolio may have 1 or many measures
2. shows the portfolio default currency
3. shows the portfolio reporting currency
4. a measure may have 1 or many reporting currencies.

I terms of 4. what is the best approach for implementation given that we have the xRates for the currencies?

Such that we create a dataframe such as that derived here:

**Create DataFrame**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index_date' : ['12/07/2016','12/07/2016','12/07/2016','12/07/2016','12/07/2016'], 
           'portfolio' : ['A','B','C','D','E'], 
           'reporting_ccy' : ['JPY','USD','USD','EUR','EUR'],
           'portfolio_ccy' : ['JPY','USD','USD','EUR','EUR'],
           'amount' : [13767.2522, 263.34, 395.01, 474.785901, 593.4823763],
           'injection' : [1,2,3,4,5],
           'to_usd' : [0.009564, 1, 1, 1.1093, 1.1093],
           'to_ccy' : [1.3167, 1.3167, 1.3167, 1.3167, 1.3167],
           'm5' : [2,4,6,8,10],
           'm6' : [1,3,5,7,9]});
```

**Concatenate & Pivot the DataFrames**

```
df_concat = pd.concat([df,df1])
df_pivot1 = df_concat.pivot_table(index='index_date',columns=['portfolio','portfolio_ccy','reporting_ccy']).swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1).sortlevel(axis=1)
df_pivot1.columns.names = ['portfolio','measures', 'portfolio_ccy', 'reporting_ccy']
```

This now shows 1 measure having many currencies.

```
df_pivot1.xs(('amount', 'A'), level=('measures','portfolio'), drop_level=False, axis=1)
```

**Question**

Is there a better way, such as adding data directly to a multiIndexed dataframe at level 3 `df_pivot1.columns.get_level_values(3).unique()`?

I would like to be able to iterate through each level and add new measures either derived from other measures using `df.assign()` or other methods.

The use case here is to add other currencies to the measures where applicable.  The concatenation and re-pivot as above does not seem optimal.

Comment: This is also explored further [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491990/adding-and-renaming-a-column-in-a-multiindex-dataframe/38493363)

Comment: Even though this is a well-formated question, I'm confused regarding your requirements. Might be completely off, but are you looking to use df_pivot and add all reporting currencies or something?
Can you use df (before pivot) to do so?

Comment: What I am implying is that there is not an easy way of adding to a lower level in a Multi-Index data frame. I have solved this and I think other questions posted by me explore this.  This is after pivot.  The reason is that you may have a MultiIndex and want to add other measures derived from data in the existing Multi-Index frame or from other data sources etc.

Comment: I'm still missing the point I guess. Wouldn't `df_pivot.ix['A','amount','JPY','GBP'] = 4` pretty much do what you need?

Comment: Your example won't work because the `df_pivot` is a different structure to what you prescibe.

Comment: A bit confusing. If you want to add a single column, then this would work: `df_pivot.loc[:, ('A','amount','JPY','USD')] = your_column` (this is what @JulienMarrec meant), and maybe apply `.sortlevel(axis=1)`. If you want to combine two data frames with hierarchical columns then  `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).sortlevel(axis=1)` should work. Anyway, a minimal example with what you'd like to have (i.e. input and output) would immensely help.

Answer (score 2):

You can append df1 row by row onto df_pivot instead of rebuilding the pivot with both frames concat together.

Appending to the end of the DataFrame would be less memory expensive than concatenating and rebuilding the pivots from scratch every time new data is received.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'index_date' : ['12/07/2016','12/07/2016','12/07/2016','12/07/2016','12/07/2016'], 
               'portfolio' : ['A','B','C','D','E'], 
               'reporting_ccy' : ['GBP','GBP','GBP','GBP','GBP'],
               'portfolio_ccy' : ['JPY','USD','USD','EUR','EUR'],
               'amount' : [100,200,300,400,500],
               'injection' : [1,2,3,4,5],
               'to_usd' : [1.3167,1.3167,1.3167,1.3167,1.3167],
               'to_ccy' : [0.009564,1,1,1.1093,1.1093],
               'm5' : [2,4,6,8,10],
               'm6' : [1,3,5,7,9]}); 

# %%
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index='index_date',columns=['portfolio','portfolio_ccy','reporting_ccy']).swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1).sortlevel(axis=1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index_date' : ['12/07/2016','12/07/2016','12/07/2016','12/07/2016','12/07/2016'], 
           'portfolio' : ['A','B','C','D','E'], 
           'reporting_ccy' : ['JPY','USD','USD','EUR','EUR'],
           'portfolio_ccy' : ['JPY','USD','USD','EUR','EUR'],
           'amount' : [13767.2522, 263.34, 395.01, 474.785901, 593.4823763],
           'injection' : [1,2,3,4,5],
           'to_usd' : [0.009564, 1, 1, 1.1093, 1.1093],
           'to_ccy' : [1.3167, 1.3167, 1.3167, 1.3167, 1.3167],
           'm5' : [2,4,6,8,10],
           'm6' : [1,3,5,7,9]}); 

df_pivot.columns.names = ['portfolio','measures', 'portfolio_ccy', 'reporting_ccy']
# instead of joining the 2 df's add df1 to df_pivot 1 row at a time. 
for i in range(len(df1)):
    row = df1.iloc[i]
    for measure in 'amount injection m5 m6 to_ccy to_usd'.split():
        df_pivot.ix[row.index_date, (row.portfolio,measure,row.portfolio_ccy, row.reporting_ccy)] = row[measure]

#%% check the end result
print(df_pivot.xs(('amount', 'A'), 
      level=('measures','portfolio'), drop_level=False, axis=1))
```

Comment: While you give the same answer as given in the question above, you have not answered the question.  The question is looking for a more optimal way to add data to a multi-index dataframe.  Please look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491990/adding-and-renaming-a-column-in-a-multiindex-dataframe/38493363) where I have explored this further.  

I'm not sure that introducing a loop is going to be more optimal than the `pd.concat` either.  This is a small example, consider this at scale and also doing calculations across measures to give derived measures.

Comment: Appending row by row on the first pivot may be less expensive on the memory than concatenating all the data and recalculating all the pivots with every new update to the data. 
Since you only need to process the new incoming data, and not the existing data over and over again.

Comment: Further efficiencies could be achieved by diverging away from the deep multiindex df towards HDF5 or SQL, but I believe this is outside the scope of the question

Answer (score 2):

I'm very confused by the information overload.
However, if I understand correctly:

> What I am implying is that there is not an easy way of adding to a lower level in a Multi-Index data frame.

---

consider `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(64).reshape(-1, 8), list('abcdefgh'), list('ABCDEFGH'))
df
```

[image]

---

we can easily add a level to the interior level of the index

```
df.index = [df.index, list('XY') * 4]
df
```

[image]

Comment: you helped with the answer in the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491990/adding-and-renaming-a-column-in-a-multiindex-dataframe/38493363) above.  This is something that feel that the Pandas core developers should help address.

Comment: Ha! I have a short memory ;-)